# Sliding window algorithm for activity recognition

Tags: matlab, sliding-window

I want to write a sliding window algorithm for use in activity recognition.

The training data is <1xN> so I'm thinking I just need to take (say `window_size=3`) the `window_size` of data and train that. I also later want to use this algorithm on a matrix 
.

I'm new to matlab so i need any advice/directions on how to implement this correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer:

```
%# nx = length(x)
%# nwind = window_size
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (1:nwind)', 1+(0:(fix(nx/nwind)-1))*nwind)-1;
```

`idx` will be a matrix of size *nwind-by-K* where *K* is the number of sliding windows (ie each column contains the indices of one sliding window).

Note that in the code above, if the last window's length is less than the desired one, it is dropped. Also the sliding windows are non-overlapping.

An example to illustrate:

```
%# lets create a sin signal
t = linspace(0,1,200);
x = sin(2*pi*5*t);

%# compute indices
nx = length(x);
nwind = 8;
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (1:nwind)', 1+(0:(fix(nx/nwind)-1))*nwind)-1;

%'# loop over sliding windows
for k=1:size(idx,2)
    slidingWindow = x( idx(:,k) );
    %# do something with it ..
end

%# or more concisely as
slidingWindows = x(idx);
```

---

**EDIT:**

For overlapping windows, let:

```
noverlap = number of overlapping elements
```

then the above is simply changed to:

```
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (1:nwind)', 1+(0:(fix((nx-noverlap)/(nwind-noverlap))-1))*(nwind-noverlap))-1;
```

An example to show the result:

```
>> nx = 100; nwind = 10; noverlap = 2;
>> idx = bsxfun(@plus, (1:nwind)', 1+(0:(fix((nx-noverlap)/(nwind-noverlap))-1))*(nwind-noverlap))-1
idx =
     1     9    17    25    33    41    49    57    65    73    81    89
     2    10    18    26    34    42    50    58    66    74    82    90
     3    11    19    27    35    43    51    59    67    75    83    91
     4    12    20    28    36    44    52    60    68    76    84    92
     5    13    21    29    37    45    53    61    69    77    85    93
     6    14    22    30    38    46    54    62    70    78    86    94
     7    15    23    31    39    47    55    63    71    79    87    95
     8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72    80    88    96
     9    17    25    33    41    49    57    65    73    81    89    97
    10    18    26    34    42    50    58    66    74    82    90    98
```

Comment: @Amro how would I adapt this to make the windows overlapping?