# comparison and shifting strings/arrays with different length in matlab

Tags: matlab, comparison, sliding-window

I have a list of strings or arrays with different length or size. I want to use the shortest string and compare with other strings by shifting the shortest string window one by one to do comparison.

Let's say I want to do addition, I have `[2 1 3]` as my shortest list and want to perform addition on `[4 5 7 8 9]`

```
1st addition: [2 1 3] + [4 5 7]
2nd addition: [2 1 3] + [5 7 8]
3rd addition: [2 1 3] + [7 8 9]
```

How can i do this using matlab?

Thanks

Comment: Strings or vectors? And how does the desired output look?

Comment: are you implementing some kind of [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) operation?

Comment: @RobertP.I do prefer vector.

Comment: @Amro No, its just part of generating features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach, if you don't care much about speed is using [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html). Note that this approach doesn't check which vector is which. `a` must be shorter than `b`.

```
a =
     1     2     3
b =
     1     3     5     2     4     6

c = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) a+b(n:n+numel(a)-1), 1:numel(b)-numel(a)+1,'UniformOutput',0).')
c =
     2     5     8
     4     7     5
     6     4     7
     3     6     9
```

Answer (score 4):

Say `A` is the longer vector and `B` the shorter one.
You can use [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) function to create a matrix where each row is a window of length 3 over `A`

```
>> hankel(A(1:3),A(3:end))
ans =
     4     5     7
     5     7     8
     7     8     9
```

Now you just need to call [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to do the desired action on each row:

```
L=numel(B); 
bsxfun(@plus, B, hankel(A(1:L),A(L:end)))
```

results in

```
ans =
     6     6    10
     7     8    11
     9     9    12
```

Where rows contain the desired output vectors.
Note that you can change `@plus` to `@minus` or any other user-defined function.

Comment: @Amro, Thaknks. Seems hankel is kinda under-appreciated. Quite simple and useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create indices of a [sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203332/97160) [window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8058977/97160) using `hankel`. Example:

```
a = [2 1 3];
b = [4 5 7 8 9];

idx = hankel(1:numel(a), numel(a):numel(b));
c = bsxfun(@plus, b(idx.'), a);
```

The result:

```
>> c
c =
     6     6    10   % [2 1 3] + [4 5 7]
     7     8    11   % [2 1 3] + [5 7 8]
     9     9    12   % [2 1 3] + [7 8 9]
```

*(Note: This assumes `b` is longer than `a`, swap them if otherwise).*

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following, assuming row arrays of doubles:

```
lenList(1) = length(list1);
lenList(2) = length(list2);


% find minumum length
[minLen, idx]   = min(lenList);

% find length difference
lenDiff    = abs(diff(lenList));

% initialize result
result     = zeros(lenDiff + 1, minLen);

% Check which list is the longest
if idx == 1
    shortList = list1;
    longList = list2;
else
    shortList = list2;
    longList = list1;
end

% Perform math
for ii = 1:(lenDiff + 1)
    result(ii, :) = shortList + longList(ii:(ii+minLen-1))
end
```