# Shifting and adding more than two arrays with different lengths - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, combinatorics, sliding-window

I have a list of strings or arrays with different length or size. I want to use the shortest string and compare with other strings by shifting the shortest string window one by one to do comparison.

Let's say I want to do addition, I have `[2 1 3]` as my shortest list and want to perform addition on `[4 5 7 8 9]`

```
1st addition: [2 1 3] + [4 5 7]
2nd addition: [2 1 3] + [5 7 8]
3rd addition: [2 1 3] + [7 8 9]
```

the example above for two arrays which i found can be solve with `hankel` function.

```
a = [2 1 3];
b = [4 5 7 8 9];

idx = hankel(1:numel(a), numel(a):numel(b));
c = bsxfun(@plus, b(idx.'), a);
```

and the result:

```
c =
     6     6    10   % [2 1 3] + [4 5 7]
     7     8    11   % [2 1 3] + [5 7 8]
     9     9    12   % [2 1 3] + [7 8 9]
```

but now, i want to perform for all of them and there are many combination. lets say arrays `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, so the possible addition can be `A+B`, `A+C`, `A+D`, `A+E`, `B+C`, `B+D`, `B+E`, `C+D`, `C+E`, `D+E`.

for example:

```
A=[2 1 3];B=[4 5 7 8 9];C=[6 9];D=[3 6 4 2 1 1];E=[4 6 9]

for A+B
 6  6  10  
 7  8  11  
 9  9  12

for A+C
 8 10
 7 12

for A+D
 5 7 7
 8 5 5
 6 3 4
 4 2 4

... and the rest
```

How can I do this using MATLAB? Many thanks

Comment: If `a = [2 1 3];
b = [4 5 7 8 9];`, what are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are now just summarizing a answer to your previous question.

Comment: @Nick , the last question was contain only two arrays, now i want to extent it to more than two arrays. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom function that works on each pair with `b` as the larger (in terms of number of elements) array and the core functionality being borrowed from your previous case -

```
function out = testfunc1(a,b) %// Shift and add arrays with different lengths

if numel(a)>numel(b) %// swap a and b,as we want b to be the larger array
    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
end
out = bsxfun(@plus, b(hankel(1:numel(a), numel(a):numel(b)).'), a);
return;
```

Now, call this function inside `arrayfun` to get all those summed up arrays as cells -

```
%// Concatenate all variables into one cell array for processing with arrayfun
allvars = cat(1,{A},{B},{C},{D},{E}) 

%// Form all combinations between the variables
allcombs = allvars(nchoosek(1:numel(allvars),2));

%// Get summed results for each pair from all vars with one of the pairs always
%// being the first variable that represents A
out =arrayfun(@(n) testfunc1(allcombs{n,1},allcombs{n,2}), 1:size(allcombs,1),'un',0) 
celldisp(out)  %//display output
```

Output on run -

```
out{1} =
     6     6    10
     7     8    11
     9     9    12
out{2} =
     8    10
     7    12
out{3} =
     5     7     7
     8     5     5
     6     3     4
     4     2     4
out{4} =
     6     7    12
out{5} =
    10    14
    11    16
    13    17
    14    18
out{6} =
     7    11    11    10    10
    10     9     9     9    10
out{7} =
     8    11    16
     9    13    17
    11    14    18
out{8} =
     9    15
    12    13
    10    11
     8    10
     7    10
out{9} =
    10    15
    12    18
out{10} =
     7    12    13
    10    10    11
     8     8    10
     6     7    10
```

Thus, the cells of `out` represent your `A+B`, `A+C`, `A+D`, `A+E`, `B+C`, `B+D` and so on outputs respectively.

Comment: A+E should be `6 7 12`.

Comment: @Cina Could you explain how? Maybe edit your question with that explanation?

Comment: @Divakar: I had a small bug in the `hankel` solution. You see `hankel` returns columns, and since we are working with row vectors `a` and `b`, we have to transpose the indices before using them on `b` and applying `bsxfun` for broadcasting the addition. The bug especially showed when `a` and `b` were of the same size. Anyway like I said, the fix is easy, just move the transpose inside the parentheses :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version:

```
% input arrays
A=[2 1 3]; B=[4 5 7 8 9]; C=[6 9]; D=[3 6 4 2 1 1]; E=[4 6 9];

% all possible pair combinations
pairs = nchoosek({A, B, C, D, E}, 2);

% make sure second one is the longest vector
ind = cellfun(@numel,pairs(:,1)) > cellfun(@numel,pairs(:,2));
pairs(ind,[1 2]) = pairs(ind,[2 1]);

c = cell(size(pairs,1),1);
for i=1:size(pairs,1)
    % the two vectors
    [a,b] = deal(pairs{i,:});

    % sliding window indices, and compute the sum
    idx = hankel(1:numel(a), numel(a):numel(b));
    c{i} = bsxfun(@plus, b(idx.'), a);
end
```

I'm reusing the [solution from you previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26355751/97160), and simply applying it to all possible pairs, with the result stored in a cell-array:

```
>> celldisp(c)
c{1} =
     6     6    10
     7     8    11
     9     9    12
c{2} =
     8    10
     7    12
c{3} =
     5     7     7
     8     5     5
     6     3     4
     4     2     4
c{4} =
     6     7    12
c{5} =
    10    14
    11    16
    13    17
    14    18
c{6} =
     7    11    11    10    10
    10     9     9     9    10
c{7} =
     8    11    16
     9    13    17
    11    14    18
c{8} =
     9    15
    12    13
    10    11
     8    10
     7    10
c{9} =
    10    15
    12    18
c{10} =
     7    12    13
    10    10    11
     8     8    10
     6     7    10
```

Each cell matches the following pairs (read across the rows):

```
>> nchoosek({'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}, 2)
ans = 
    'A'    'B'
    'A'    'C'
    'A'    'D'
    'A'    'E'
    'B'    'C'
    'B'    'D'
    'B'    'E'
    'C'    'D'
    'C'    'E'
    'D'    'E'
```

Comment: For some reason I thought OP wanted `A+B, A+C, A+D and A+E` only. I guess I got caught up in the outputs shown at the end of post. Do you mind if I use `nchoosek` too in my solution? :)

Comment: @Amro Okay so edited my solution and hopefully the only thing borrowed is that `nchoosek`.

Comment: @Amro Interesting, these arrayfun and cellfun are loopy codes anyway, but OP might prefer short/compact codes :)  You had my +1, mainly because I had to borrow that `nchoosek` ;)

Comment: @Cina: ah good catch, I edited the solution. The fix is very easy, change `bsxfun(@plus, b(idx).', a)` into `bsxfun(@plus, b(idx.'), a)` (transpose the indices before indexing not after)!